# I want to scan some words, and put them in a string array, then print it.

Tags: c

I want to scan some words, and put them in a string array, then print it. But all i got is some memory garbage...

```
char arrayOfWords[50][50];
char array2[50][50];

int i;
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    scanf ("%s" , arrayOfWords[i]);
    array2[i][50] = arrayOfWords[i];

}

for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    printf ("%s\n" , array2[i]);
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Why 2 dimensional array? You just need a single big enough char array as a buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just copy strings using the assignment operator (`=`).

Change:

```
array2[i][50] = arrayOfWords[i];
```

to:

```
strcpy(array2[i], arrayOfWords[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing i see here is:

```
array2[i][50] = arrayOfWords[i];
```

it is not a way to copy character arrays in c.
use [memcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) or [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) or similar to achieve expected result.
e.g.:

```
strcpy(array2[i], arrayOfWords[i]);
```